# Three methods for inverting a matrix in R all give different results

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

I have a 316x316 matrix (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qjo025p2ea59dg/data.rda?dl=0).

When I invert it using `solve`, I get an error:

```
> ans1 <- solve(data)
Error in solve.default(data) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.73244e-17
```

When I invert it using `chol2inv`, I get a matrix where every value is 1.492617e+12

```
> ans2 <- chol2inv(chol(data))
> head(ans2[1:3, 1:3])
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12
[2,] 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12
[3,] 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12 1.492617e+12
```

And when I invert it using `ginv`, I get a still different result:

```
> library(MASS)
> ans3 <- ginv(data)
> head(ans3[1:3, 1:3])
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 11.16048596  0.02262223 -0.5915676
[2,]  0.02262223 12.07619895  0.4329126
[3,] -0.59156765  0.43291261 23.1798179
```

Does anyone have thoughts as to what is causing these discrepancies and/or, how one should proceed in such a situation?

Comment: Those are not the inverse of the matrix. Note that your matrix is singular. It does not have an inverse. the `ginv` gives the generalized inverse and that is not the inverse

Comment: and: how you proceed with a singular matrix depends on what you want to do with the results. The generalized inverse you show might be useful, or singular value decomposition might give you useful output. Don't believe the `chol2inv` results (they're most likely to be just noise).